# Sitecore Site/Item Publishing hangs at Initializing

Tags: sitecore

We had a problem with core database, that had been restored by the previous day's backup database.

After that the site is working fine but, we are having problem with publishing any changes. Once er hit the publish button the "Publish Initializing.." message just keeps continuing prolonged time. Noting is captured in the the event log as of "Publish Start/End" neither.

So when we tried cleaning up the master/web database using Database Cleanup tool, SQL error pops up.

Do anyone have resolution for such problem?

This is the error I get while "web" database clean up.

```
Job started: CleanUpDatabases|System.Exception: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.Data.DataException: Error executing SQL command:  declare @x bigint set @x = 0 DECLARE @item TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier,parentID uniqueidentifier) INSERT INTO @item (ID,parentID)   SELECT  [ID],[ParentID] FROM [Items]  DECLARE @temp TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier) WHILE (SELECT count(id) FROM @item ) <> @x begin set @x = (SELECT count(id) FROM @item ) delete from @temp; insert into @temp (ID)   SELECT  id FROM @item where parentID  = @nullId update @item SET Parentid =@nullId where Parentid  in (select id from @temp) delete from @item where  id  in (select id from @temp) end UPDATE [Items] SET [Parentid] = @nullId where [ID]  in (select id from @item) ; DELETE from [Items] where [ID] in (select id from @item) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Execute>b__14()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.CleanupDatabase(CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.CleanupDatabase(CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Databases.CleanUp.CleanUpForm.Cleaner.CleanUp()|Job ended: CleanUpDatabases (units processed: )
```

Comment: What kind of SQL errors are displayed? And maybe you can check the Job Viewer in Sitecore Rocks if it is running any job at all.

Comment: Below is the exact error message. Sorry, the issue we are discussing is in live site, so can't connect to that server with Sitecore Rocks. Thanks..

Comment: An alternative to the Rocks Job Viewer: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/sitecore-job-viewer-see-what-sitecore-is-doing-behind-your-back/ You should be able to drop this in to your live application without causing an app pool recycle (Assuming you're allowed to do so).

Answer (score 5):

An explanation is provided here:

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/timeout-error-when-running-cleanupdatabases-job/

You need to increase the `DefaultSQLTimeout` setting in the Sitecore config. 
Try setting it to 30 minutes.

```xml
<setting name=”DataProviderTimeout” value=”00:30:00″ />
```

Also answered here:

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/timeout-error-when-running-cleanupdatabases-job/

Comment: Am wondering if this could be something else and not be timeout, because everything worked fine until we did the "core" database replace(older version of the database).

Comment: I'm really just addressing the exception you're getting. For the publishing issue, I suggest installing the job viewer aspx I recommended in my other comment.

Comment: The issue has been magically vanished over the next day morning.. I suppose the IIS app pool clear would have fixed the issue (or even may be off business hours server idleness could have flushed the app pool). 

Thanks everybody for the kindly response.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things and the only one that **worked** was to **synchronize** the time **between** the **web server** and the **database server**.

You can do it either updating the time in both servers or using Internet Time tab.

[image]

After that, it worked fine.

This worked using Sitecore 6.6.