# Sitecore publish not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

When I click on publish, it says initializing and the process goes on. It happens with both publish item or publish site (Smart publish).

Using Sitecore 8.2. The instance is in the local PC and the DB is the remote server. There is no issue when creating a new item.

I checked the logs. There are two files with the name "log". Is this normal.
The first log file has the below error:

> ManagedPoolThread #16 14:12:45 ERROR Unable to connect to server
>   localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017.

The second one has this:

> 12488 14:13:18 ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   aggregation/automationRangeManager Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.GetRightKey()    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.RangeManagerAgent.Execute()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

I do not have MongoDB installed in the local PC or in the remote DB server, because, this is not needed for this project.

**This worked for me:**

1. Go to Website\App_Config\Include
2. Open Sitecore.Xdb.config
3. Set Xdb.Enabled to false and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to false.

Comment: To fix the log errors, you need to set `Xdb.Enabled` to `false`. Check the documentation for details: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker

Comment: Publishing problems don't seem to be related to the log errors, though. Could you please elaborate on what happens during the publish, exactly?

Comment: After clicking on publish, the publish popup appears where there is the wait gif and the popup has the word initializing. It doesn't go any further after that. This is a fresh instance with hardly 3-4 new items

Comment: try disabling Xdb as Dmytro suggest, I think that will solve the issue

Comment: I do not find it in web.config or sitecore.config. Where will it be

Comment: It's in `App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Xdb.config`. Set `Xdb.Enabled=false`

Comment: Interestingly, according to [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35884772/236660), this issue may occur if server time is set incorrectly on one of the machines.

Comment: I have another question. Was your Sitecore 8.2 instance set up from scratch? Or did you upgrade from an earlier Sitecore version?

Comment: @jammykam. Thank you for mentioning the config. I'm surprised the official doc mentions the step but does not say where to find those properties. It is a fresh 8.2 instance and not an upgrade.

Comment: If it's not the server time issue mentioned above: we had a very similar issue that was related to lock files not being deleted.  Try going to <install_folder>\Data\indexes\\__system and deleting any *.lock files there.

Comment: This worked for me as well:

Go to Website\App_Config\Include
Open Sitecore.Xdb.config
Set Xdb.Enabled to false and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to false.